# Strings behvior on C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I want to understand a number of things about the strings on C:

I could not understand why you can not change the string in a normal assignment. (But only through the functions of string.h), for example: I can't do `d="aa"` (d is a pointer of char or a array of char).
Can someone explain to me what's going on behind the scenes - the compiler gives to run such thing and you receive segmentation fault error.

Something else, I run a program in C that contains the following lines:

```
char c='a',*pc=&c;
printf("Enter a string:");
scanf("%s",pc);
printf("your first char is: %c",c);
printf("your string is: %s",pc);
```

1. If I put more than 2 letters (on scanf) I get segmentation fault error, why is this happening?
2. If I put two letters, the first letter printed right! And the string is printed with a lot of profits (incorrect)
3. If I put a letter, the letter is printed right! And the string is printed with a lot of profits and at the end something weird (a square with four numbers containing zeros and ones)

Can anyone explain what is happening behind?

***Please note:*** I do not want the program to work, I did not ask the question to get suggestions for another program, I just want to understand what happens behind the scenes in these situations.

Comment: First line is wrong, it should be `char c='a'`, with single-quotes.

Comment: `c` is a single `char`, where do you think the rest of the string goes to?

Comment: how it is possible to store more than one letter to a single char type variable? you need to use character array instead this

Comment: I wan't to understand why it is not work with pointer(I do this with array - I don't ask a suggestions). pointer is like array, it is point to the begging of the string

Comment: @Hodaya Shalom : pointer is not array,Pointer itself is a variable it holds the address of another variable.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil : But is it can not behave like an array (from the address it holds, and so on)

Comment: @SujithKarivelil! An array's name is simply a pointer to it's first element!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings almost do not exist in C (except as C string literals like `"abc"` in some C source file).

In fact, strings are mostly a convention: a C string is an array of `char` whose last element is the zero char `'\0'`.

So declaring

```
 const char s[] = "abc";
```

is *exactly* the same as

```
 const char s[] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
```

in particular, `sizeof(s)` is 4 (3+1) in both cases (and so is `sizeof("abc")`).

The standard C library contains a lot of functions (such as [strlen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) or [strncpy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html)...) which obey and/or presuppose the convention that strings are zero-terminated arrays of `char`-s.

Better code would be:

```
char buf[16]="a",*pc= buf;
printf("Enter a string:"); fflush(NULL);
scanf("%15s",pc);
printf("your first char is: %c",buf[0]);
printf("your string is: %s",pc);
```

Some comments: be afraid of [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). When reading a string, always give a bound to the read string, or else use a function like [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) which [dynamically allocates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) the string in the heap. Beware of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) (use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ...)

When computing a string, be also aware of the maximum size. See [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (avoid `sprintf`).

Often, you adopt the convention that a string is returned and dynamically allocated in the heap. You may want to use [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if your system provides it. But you should adopt the convention that the *calling function* (or something else, but well defined in your head) is [free(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html)-ing the string.

Your program can be semantically wrong and by bad luck happening to *sometimes* work. Read carefully about [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Avoid it absolutely (your points 1,2,3 are probable UB). Sadly, an UB may happen to sometimes "work".

To explain some actual undefined behavior, you have to take into account your particular implementation: the compiler, the flags -notably optimization flags- passed to the compiler, the operating system, the kernel, the processor, the phase of the moon, etc etc... Undefined behavior is often *non reproducible* (e.g. because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) etc...), read about [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). To explain the behavior of points 1,2,3 you need to dive into implementation details; look into the assembler code (`gcc -S -fverbose-asm`) produced by the compiler.

I suggest you to compile your code with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. using `gcc -Wall -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...), to improve the code till you got no warning, and to learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to run your code step by step.

Comment: Can you explain to me why when I point this single character its can not put the string on the continuation of memory?

Comment: Because a string is zero terminated. so `"a"` needs two bytes.

Comment: "a" is a mistake of the text only! in thr program I wrote 'a' and I corrected it here

Comment: Read then think more about *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 1):

**If I put more than 2 letters (on scanf) I get segmentation fault error, why is this happening?**

Because memory is allocated for only one byte.
See `char c` and assigned with `"a"`. Which is equal to `'a'` and `'\0'` is written in one byte memory location.

If `scanf()` uses this memory for reading more than one byte, then this is simply **undefined behavior**.

Comment: So why no error when I write two letters, was not it supposed to give me to write only one letter (as in char)?

Comment: If you compiled with `-Wall` you might have noticed. `Assignment of Char* to char` kind of warning.

Answer (score 0):

`char c="a";` is a wrong declaration in c language since even a single character is enclosed within a pair of double quotes(`""`) will treated as string in C because it is treated as "a\0" since all strings ends with a '\0' null character.
`char c="a";` is wrong where as `char c='c';` is correct.

Also note that the memory allocated for char is only 1byte, so it can hold only one character, memory allocation details  for datatypes are described bellow

[image: Operator Types]

Comment: So why no error when I write two letters, was not it supposed to give me to write only one letter (as in char)?

Comment: `char c="a";` is shows complie error http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php